# installshield - how to add files from specific folder

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield, path-variables

I want to add files to my installer from specific folder, I also create a 'standard path variable' for the folder. But I don't know how to use it to add from there the files.
I want that the installer will get the files from this specific folder at any machine that the installer will run on it.

Answer (score 0):

> ***UPDATE***: Since this was just down-voted. There is a feature that allows files to be added dynamically. [Dynamic File Linking](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield26helplib/helplibrary/IHelpDynamicFileLinking.htm). My
> experience with this feature is that it causes problems for patching
> and upgrades - even if you are careful. Be aware of this before using
> it (might not be important with patching).

---

Not sure I understand, but to add files to your setup just use the files and folder view:

[image]

Path variables are generally created automatically by Installshield when you add files, or you can set one to point to your top level relase folder:

Path Variable

- **MyPath1** = C:\My Setups\Setup 1\

Folders:

- C:\My Setups\Setup 1\Folder 1\App.exe => [**MyPath1**]Folder 1\App.exe
- C:\My Setups\Setup 1\Folder 2\support.dll  => [**MyPath1**]Folder 2\support.dll

Then you can move the whole folder C:\My Setups\Setup 1\ to another computer and location and just adjust the MyPath1 path variable in the Path Variables view.

Comment: I know this way, but I don't want to copy the file to the installer. I want that the installer will get the file from the machine that it running on.